# Refactoring documents in a NoSQL database

Tags: nosql

I am doing some reading into the benefits of using the NoSQL style of document database, and one of my concerns is how to deal with the 'refactoring' of data should the need arise.

Contrived example from someone who has never actually worked with NoSQL:

> Suppose in MongoDB we have a document called User which has an embedded document called Address, and later on we decide that the Address document should be moved out into a new collection.

What are the possibile approaches for doing that, with consideration for downtime, performance, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schema changes are pretty easy when you don't have a formally defined schema - all you have to do is update your own code so it can handle both old and new documents, usually by including both old and new fields and moving data from old to new either on load or before save as appropriate.

Since there won't be data version conflicts between the code and database there is no downtime, and it is trivial to call your existing load/save code on all documents if you want to do a complete migration and remove support for the old documents.

Changing indexed properties is a little more complicated, but still easier than making changes to a SQL schema.

Comment: Thanks for the update - what about if I _really_ wanted to migrate the data to the new schema so that the code didn't need to support the old schema? I have a feeling it can be done using Map/Reduce but I've not found any examples...

Comment: Yes, map/reduce should work - NoSQL hasn't been around long enough to generate lots of examples for migrating from anything other than SQL. That approach will require downtime though, and performance may not be any better than doing the processing on the client.